# Are there already a series of switches/commands/aliases to initiate vim and auto backup to new file when writing out

Tags: backup

...with confirmation that is somewhat similar to the "you are in RO mode" that you get as a layer of security if you run the command as `view`.

I want a single command [that I may alias to something simple] that says, "Automatically make the backup directory for the back up files that will be created every time a save is made of the data before it was written.

It would be cool if there was also a way to write to another file that this file was opened in *"Uncertain I won't regret these changes"* mode, so that if that file is ever opened outside of that mode... vim will know that that might have been a mistake, ask, and allow a Y/n that will keep the file name or delete it from the list of "uncertain" mode files.

And, I don't want the backups to replace the backup. I want a new backup to be added, numbered.

I could build this... but if there is already a set of commands and switches and aliased things that can produce an effect that is similar, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: See `:help backup`, `:help backupdir`, `:help backupext` and `:help writebackup`. With `backupext` you can add timestamps to the filename (see help). To write to another file, just do `:w otherFile.txt`.

Comment: Hmm. Version control (git/mercurial)?